# How to display a list of values with irregular step size with Slider?

Tags: qt, qml, controls

I am trying to display a list of values with a slider in QML. Those values have an irregular step size, i.e [10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100]. How would i go about doing this with a QML slider (must be a slider due to design constraints)? Slider does not have a model property sadly, so I cant do it that way. Of course i could create my own custom slider from scratch, but if there is an easier way, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

Setup the range and the step of the slider, e.g.:

```
from: 0; to: 5; stepSize: 1
```

Use a JS function to convert the slider value to whatever you need, e.g.:

```
function hash(x) {
    var table = [10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100];

    return table[x];
}
```

**Note:** For complex conversions consider calling a method of a class from the C++ backend.

### Example

Here is a simple example I have written for you to demonstrate the proposed solution:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 640; height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("QML Slider Values")

    function hash(x) {
        var table = [10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100];

        return table[x];
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Slider {
            id: slider

            from: 0; to: 5; stepSize: 1
        }

        Text {
            text: hash(slider.value)
            Layout.alignment: Layout.Center
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

Inspired by @fallerd, I rewrote the `ColumnLayout`-part a little bit moderner:

```
ColumnLayout {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    Slider {
        id: slider

        property var hashTable: [10, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100];
        readonly property int hashedValue: (() => hashTable[value])();

        from: 0; to: hashTable.length - 1; stepSize: 1
    }

    Text {
        text: slider.hashedValue
        Layout.alignment: Layout.Center
    }
}
```

Comment: As a slight improvement, you might declare the `table` array outside the function as a `property var` so that you can bind to it dynamically. For example, bind the `slider.to` to `table.length - 1` so that you don't have to manually maintain their relationship.

Comment: @fallerd, thank you for the suggestion. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Of course, using an intermediate array and its index as slider value. Simple. I guess my brain was mush after all yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: @Tanzmaus, you are very welcome!